# YUI3 Datatable loaded with JSON displays only no results to display (Scala/Play 2.1)

Tags: yui

I am new to YUI but I veteran of JQuery UI.  So this one has me stumped.  I cannot get my Datatable to render with the Rest service.  I have two version of the code.  One that I use the captured JSON object from the service as just a data object and a local datasource.  That one works fine.  When I attempt to switch to the GET plugin and get it from the service.  It just never renders.

My local example:

```
@main("Play 2.1") {

<script type="text/javascript">

    YUI().use("datatable", "datasource-local", "datasource-jsonschema", "datatable-datasource", function (Y) {

        var data = [
            {"script":{"id":34534,
                "scriptText":"234523452345234",
                "modifiedDate":1367525647000,
                "status":"Reviewed",
                "qcDate":1367526006000,
                "location":{"id":1},
                "orderInfo":{"id":1,
                    "orderName":"Order Name",
                    "dealerName":"Dealer Name"}
            }},
            {"script":{"id":656435,
                "scriptText":"36536543636365",
                "modifiedDate":1367525646000,
                "status":"Reviewed",
                "qcDate":1367526017000,
                "location":{"id":1},
                "orderInfo":{"id":43534534,
                    "orderName":"Order Name",
                    "dealerName":"Dealer Name"}
            }}
        ];

        var localDataSource = new Y.DataSource.Local({source:data});

        localDataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
            schema:{
                resultListLocator:"",
                resultFields:[
                    {
                        key:"id",
                        locator:"script.id"
                    },
                    {
                        key:"scriptText",
                        locator:"script.scriptText"
                    },
                    {
                        key:"modifiedDate",
                        locator:"script.modifiedDate"
                    }

                ]
            }
        });


        var simple = new Y.DataTable({
            columns:["id", "scriptText", "modifiedDate"],
            summary:"Example Summary",
            caption:"Example Caption"
        });

        simple.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, {
            datasource:localDataSource
        });

        simple.render("#dataGrid");
        simple.datasource.load();

    });

</script>

<span id="listView">
            <div id="dataGrid" style="height: 95%;width: 100%;"></div>
        </span>


<div id="dataCheckArea">
    <h3>RAW DATA AREA</h3>
    <ul>
        @records.map {record =>
        <li>@record.toString</li>
        }
    </ul>

</div>

}
```

My REST Service example:

```
@main("Welcome to Play 2.1") {

<script type="text/javascript">

    YUI().use("datatable", "datasource-get", "datasource-jsonschema", "datatable-datasource", function (Y) {

        var dataSource = new Y.DataSource.Get({
            source:"http://localhost:9000/reviewRecords?q=query"
        });

        dataSource.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
            schema:{
                resultListLocator:"",
                resultFields:[
                    {
                        key:"id",
                        locator:"script.id"
                    },
                    {
                        key:"scriptText",
                        locator:"script.scriptText"
                    },
                    {
                        key:"modifiedDate",
                        locator:"script.modifiedDate"
                    }

                ]
            }
        });


        var dataGrid = new Y.DataTable({
            columns:["id", "scriptText", "modifiedDate"],
            summary:"Example Summary",
            caption:"Example Caption"
        });

        dataGrid.plug(Y.Plugin.DataTableDataSource, { datasource:dataSource });

        dataGrid.render("#dataGrid");
        dataGrid.datasource.load();

    });

</script>

        <span id="listView">
            <div id="dataGrid" style="height: 95%;width: 100%;"></div>
        </span>
```

** edited because the original submission lost my second code block.

Comment: Attaching example which doesn’t work would be probably better idea.

Comment: I had it originally but the site gave me an error during original submission.  Thanks for pointing it out for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem wasn't with my javascript code.  The issue was with how I was sending the response.  The YUI framework expects that the response will be wrapped in a callback function.  When I changed my response to give a JSONP response with the callback it all started working.

```
YUI.Env.DataSource.callbacks.yui_3_11_0_1_1379097239018_187([
        {"script":{"id":34534,
            "scriptText":"234523452345234",
            "modifiedDate":1367525647000,
            "status":"Reviewed",
            "qcDate":1367526006000,
            "location":{"id":1},
            "orderInfo":{"id":1,
                "orderName":"Order Name",
                "dealerName":"Dealer Name"}
        }},
        {"script":{"id":656435,
            "scriptText":"36536543636365",
            "modifiedDate":1367525646000,
            "status":"Reviewed",
            "qcDate":1367526017000,
            "location":{"id":1},
            "orderInfo":{"id":43534534,
                "orderName":"Order Name",
                "dealerName":"Dealer Name"}
        }}
    ])
```

I did this by using a JSONP call in the method response from Scala/Play 2.1

```
def reviewRecords(q: String, callback: String) = Action {

val reviewRecords = reviewRecordsService.currentReviewRecords

Ok(new Jsonp(callback, Json.toJson(DataTablesReturnObject(reviewRecords.size, reviewRecords.toArray)))).as("application/json")
```

}

I am going to edit the title of my original question to include the keywords for Play 2.1 and Scala because this ends up being a little different than a Java response.